# Number of days between dates

Tags: ruby, date, date-arithmetic

I have two dates: `start date` and `end date`. I want to calculate the number of days between `end date` and `start date`. If `start date` is `1-11-2011`, `end date` is `2-11-2012`, and I put `start date - end date`, it will show the number of days as `1`, and will not count the months and years. How can I do this in ruby? Kindly help me.

Comment: You can't have a variable named `start date` or `end date`. Do you actually have something like `start_date`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'date'

start_date = Date.parse('1-11-2011')
# => #<Date: 2011-11-01 … >
end_date   = Date.parse('2-11-2012')
# => #<Date: 2012-11-02 … >

inclusive_days_in_range = (start_date .. end_date).count
# => 368
```

Or if you care about efficiency (two orders of magnitude faster):

```
inclusive_days_in_range = (end_date - start_date) + 1
# => 368
```

Please note that if you use `Date.parse`, the given date string like yours will be interpreted as if it begins with the day and is followed by month and year. If that is not what you want, you must use the `Date.strptime` method to manually specify your date format, even if I don't know of any nation on Earth where this would be the conventional date format. To be clear and avoid string parsing you could also initialize Date objects the following way:

```
Date.new(2012, 1, 11)
```

Another good idea would be to use [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (YYYY-MM-DD) format in your application internals and only convert them into localized representations on demand to improve clarity.

Comment: don't do `(start_date ... end_date).count`, this will initialise lots of Date objects. Do `end_date - start_date` instead

Comment: Yes, if efficiency is relevant, you should do that. But then you have to be aware that one day in the range is not counted. You would have to add `result + 1`.

Answer (score 5):

```
require "date"
(
  Date.strptime("2-11-2012", "%m-%d-%Y") -
  Date.strptime("1-11-2011", "%m-%d-%Y")
).to_i + 1
# => 397
```

Comment: As I stated in a comment to my own answer, when subtracting dates, you won't get the count of all days, as if you had an inclusive range but one less.

Comment: @aef Right. I missed that part for this answer. I corrected it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
time_ago_in_words(pending_requests.created_at)
```

This will take care of days and hours both
like for example

```
about 17 hours ago
```

and

```
3 days ago
```